# Does one need to complete the GTA Online achievements to receive "The Los Santos Legend" platinum trophy?

Tags: achievements, grand-theft-auto-v, ps4, grand-theft-auto-online

So for most of my time in GTA V I'm senselessly killing people, but about two weeks back I decided to try for 100% completion. I completed that task yesterday (by finishing golf below par lol) and I was expecting that to be the platinum trophy. I was incorrect and now know that it is "The Los Santos Legend". On PS4 it divides each section of trophies down, like GTA V, GTA ONLINE, etc. I only need five more offline achievements but I am worried that I will also have to complete the GTA Online section.

What do I have to do, achievement wise, to get the trophy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this trophy guide](http://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/grand-theft-auto-v/211719-grand-theft-auto-v-trophy-guide-roadmap.html), **yes**, you will need to earn the 17 Online trophies to unlock the Platinum trophy. In particular, step 4 of the process to get the platinum trophy simply states:

> Now it is time to step into the world of GTA Online to mop up the remaining trophies.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get 100% of the available achievements, Online and Story to unlock "The Los Santos Legend".